# Receiving no output when NOT clause is used in SQL to detect duplicate records under same values

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, duplicates

Im new to SQL and trying to understand how i can find if similar fields exist across different values in a column:

My code:

```
WITH LOC_CTE AS
(SELECT DISTINCT fa.AccountKey, dce.EmailAddress , dcp.Phone , dpo.BrandName, dpo.BrandId
FROM Fact.Account fa
LEFT JOIN Dim.PetOwner dpo ON dpo.PetOwnerKey = fa.PetOwnerKey
LEFT JOIN Dim.RatingAddress dra ON dra.RatingAddressKey = fa.RatingAddressKey
LEFT JOIN Dim.CustomerEmail dce ON dce.CustomerEmailKey = fa.CurrentCustomerEmailKey
LEFT JOIN Dim.CustomerPrimaryPhone dcp ON dcp.CustomerPrimaryPhoneKey = fa.CurrentCustomerPrimaryPhoneKey
)


SELECT * FROM (
SELECT  LOC_CTE.*
   ,row_number() over (partition by EmailAddress,Phone,BrandId order by BrandName) as seqnum
      from LOC_CTE
           ) Q
where seqnum >= 1;
```

The output gives me:

```
AccountKeyEmailAddress  Phone     BrandName BrandId seqnum
389082  0160150@m**.edu   2098579**    AP       4   1
430223  01co***st**e@msn.com8655677**9  AP      4   1
430224  01cor**s**e@msn.com 8655677**9  AP      4   2
531443  01mar**01@gmail.com 73278**63   AP      4   1
544454  01mu**rmyra@gmail.com 8133**793 AP      4   1
548374  03b**y13@gmail.com  30130**93   AP      4   1
216594  03d**ado@gmail.com  50363**34   AP      4   1
377919  03d**ado@gmail.com  50363**734  AP      4   2
486237  03d**ado@gmail.com  50363**734  HP      3   3
532010  041**hen@gmail.com  85749**455  AP      4   1
365925  05bla**ro*e21@gmail.com 682365**51  AP  4   1
365926  05bla**ro*e21@gmail.com 682365**51  HP  3   2
```

So as can be observed in my output, I am able to detect duplicate records and sequence of its duplicity. Bu what I want is that my final report also detects if the same person(email and phone number) is repeated under a different brand. For example if you notice in the last two rows of the ouput it is the same individual but under 2 different brands and brand ID. But I just want to isolate these instances and generate an output which only shows the original duplicate along with the duplicate that comes up under a different brand/brandID. How do I do this?

I tried to edit the last line of my clause and integrated a NOT clause but I did not receive any output and neither any error. My syntax may be wrong but hope this helps with the logic

```
where seqnum >= 1 AND NOT BrandID = BrandID ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select *
from (select LOC_CTE.*,
             row_number() over (partition by EmailAddress,Phone,BrandId order by BrandName) as seqnum,
             min(brandid) over (partition by EmailAddress, Phone) as min_brandid,
             max(brandid) over (partition by EmailAddress, Phone) as max_brandid
      from LOC_CTE
           ) Q
where seqnum >= 1 and  -- this condition is useless
      min_brandid <> max_brandid;
```

Comment: But how do I detect at what Specific account key the other brandId exists. Also this shows min and max brand id but what if there are brandID between them. For example, My max brand Id is 13 and min is 1 but what if one person has duplicate accounts under more brand id like 1,2,3,4,13. How can I detect the ones in between too?

Comment: @hartvillezillow . . . This shows the *rows* that match your conditions.  Hence, it returns the same rows you are getting now, but filtered based on what your question describes.